# Discord V14 message event

Tags: discord.js, sendmessage

me want to bot reply to user that me want
if the user that me want, write Hey bot say hoy
not for everyone just the user that me want me mean me give him the user id if user id was true reply to him and say hoy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to do something like

```js
if (message.author.id == "1234567890") //replace 1234567890 with desired ID
{
    message.reply("hoy");
}
```

This will check if the sender's ID is 1234567890, and if so, reply with the word "hoy".